# printing both the conditional outputs in python

Tags: python-3.x

here is a small program below,the positive flow if the word is a plaindrome works fine and gives a correct output,but if the word is not a palindrome it is printing both the print statements.any help appreciated..

```
x=input("Enter the word or sentance :")
a=len(x)
if a==1:
    print("it is a one letter palindrome")
elif a>1:
    y=0
    while y<(a/2):
        if x[y]==x[-(y+1)]:
            print(x[y])
        else:
            print("it is not palindrome") 
            break
        y=y+1
       print("it is a palindrome")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing a space before the last print call, so it is being called after the while loop terminates.

Update:

Python is sensitive to spacing, and I can't see if that is fixed in your comment. Try this:

```
x=input("Enter the word or sentance :")
a=len(x)
if a==1:
    print("it is a one letter palindrome")
elif a>1:
    y=0
    while y<(a/2):
        if x[y]==x[-(y+1)]:
            print(x[y])
        else:
            print("it is not palindrome") 
            break
        y=y+1
        print("it is a palindrome")
```

Comment: tried this code still the same:x=input("Enter the word or sentance :")
a=len(x)
if a==1:
    print("it is a one letter palindrome")
elif a>1:
    y=0
    while y<(a/2):
        if x[y]==x[-(y+1)]:
            print(x[y])
        else:
            print("not palendrome") 
            break
        y=y+1
        print("palendrome")